# Losing my file's data after closing the file

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a file that holds records for the students in a school, every thing is going fine apart from one, that is the data is being lost after i close the program .
what's the problem ?

program starts here :

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>

    using namespace std;
```

This is the struct that will be used to process the records .

```
    /*a struct ogrenci and name it ogr_t with typedef*/
    typedef struct ogrenci
    {
    int kyt_no, ogrno, vize, final;
    float ort;
    char ad[10];
    char soyad[10];
    }ogr_t;
    /*End struct*/

    void creatfile();//To create the file "Kayit.dat" if it was not created .
```

functions prototypes and main()

```
    int menu();
    void addrecord(FILE *ptr); 
    void updaterecord(FILE *ptr);
    void deleterecord(FILE *ptr);
    void listrecords(FILE *ptr);
    void searchrecord(FILE *ptr);
    double findavg(FILE *ptr);

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    FILE *fp;
    int request;
    int choice;
    printf("1- Creat the File \"Kayit.dat\" if it was not created .\n\n"
           "#NOTE: this choice will clear the data saved if the file was created earlier .\n\n"
           "2- To continue if the file is already created .\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:creatfile();
    case 2:
        system("cls");
        if ((fp = fopen("kayit.dat", "rb+")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("File was not opened.");
        }
        else
        {
            while ((request = menu()) != 6)
            {
                switch (request)
                {
                case 1:addrecord(fp); break;
                case 2:updaterecord(fp); break;
                case 3:deleterecord(fp); break;
                case 4:listrecords(fp); break;
                case 5:searchrecord(fp); break;
                default:printf("undefined\n");break;
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }break;
    default:printf("Undefined\n");break;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

after asking the user in    main() this function creats the file kayit.dat

```
    void creatfile()
    {
    FILE *fp;
    ogr_t bos_ogr = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, "", "" };
    if ((fp = fopen("kayit.dat", "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File was not opened");
    }
    else
    {   //to create a file and initialize it with an empty 100 student record .
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            fwrite(&bos_ogr, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, fp);
        }//end for
    }
    system("cls");
    }
```

This is the menu that the user will be represented with in main() .

```
    int menu(void)
    {
    int x;
    printf("What do you want to do :\n\n"
        "1= Add record .\n"
        "2= Update record .\n"
        "3= Delete Record .\n"
        "4= list all the records .\n"
        "5= Search for a specific record .\n"
        "6= Quit .\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    system("cls");
    return x;
    }
```

This function adds a new record using random access .

```
    void addrecord(FILE *ptr)
    {
    ogr_t record = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, "", "" };
    int accnum;
    char c;
    /*Enter a record number and search if is was already input*/
    printf(" Enter a record number for the new student < 1 - 100 > .");
    scanf("%d", &accnum);
    fseek(ptr, (accnum - 1)*sizeof(ogr_t), SEEK_SET);
    fread(&record, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
    if (record.kyt_no!=0)
    {
        printf("this record is already full .\n");
        printf("press and key to continue...\n");
        if (c = _getche())
        {
            system("cls");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s\n", "Name", "SureName", "StudentNum", "MidtermNote", "FinalNote");
        fscanf(stdin, "%s%s%d%d%d", record.ad, record.soyad, &record.ogrno, &record.vize, &record.final);
        record.kyt_no = accnum;
        fseek(ptr, (record.kyt_no - 1)*sizeof(ogr_t), SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&record, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
    }
    system("cls");
    }
```

Update the record chosen by the user.

```
    void updaterecord(FILE *ptr)
    {
    ogr_t record1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, "", "" };
    int accnum;
    char c;
    printf(" Enter the student's record number that you want to update  < 1 - 100 > .");
    scanf("%d", &accnum);
    fseek(ptr, (accnum - 1)*sizeof(ogr_t), SEEK_SET);
    fread(&record1, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
    if (record1.kyt_no == 0)
    {
        printf("This record is empty\n");
        printf("press and key to continue...\n");
        if (c= _getche())
        {
            system("cls");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the new informations\n");
        printf("%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s\n", "Name", "SureName", "StudentNum", "MidtermNote", "FinalNote");
        fscanf(stdin, "%s%s%d%d%d", record1.ad, record1.soyad, &record1.ogrno, &record1.vize, &record1.final);
        record1.kyt_no = accnum;
        fseek(ptr, (record1.kyt_no - 1)*sizeof(ogr_t), SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&record1, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
        system("cls");
    }

    }
```

Delete  a record chosen by the user after checking that's empty or not .

```
    void deleterecord(FILE *ptr)
    {
    ogr_t bos_ogr = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, "", "" };
    ogr_t record2;
    int accnum;
    char c;
        printf("Enter the record for the student that you want delete < 1 - 100 >\n");
        fscanf(stdin, "%d", &accnum);
        fseek(ptr, (accnum - 1)*sizeof(ogr_t), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&record2, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
        if (record2.kyt_no == 0)
        {
            printf("The record is already empty .\n");
            printf("press and key to continue...\n");
            if (c = _getche())
            {
                system("cls");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fseek(ptr, (accnum - 1)*sizeof(ogr_t), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&bos_ogr, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
            system("cls");
        }
    }
```

List all the records in the file .

```
void listrecords(FILE *ptr)
{
    ogr_t record_prnt;
    char c;
    printf("%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s\n", "RecordNo", "Name", "Surname", "StudentNum", "MidtermNote", "FinalNote");
    rewind(ptr);
    fread(&record_prnt, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
    while (!feof(ptr))
    {
        if (record_prnt.kyt_no == 0)
        {
            record_prnt = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, "", "" };
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%-13d%-13s%-13s%-13d%-13d%-13d\n",
                record_prnt.kyt_no, record_prnt.ad,
                record_prnt.soyad, record_prnt.ogrno,
                record_prnt.vize, record_prnt.final);
        }
        fread(&record_prnt, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
    }
    printf("press any key to contiue ...\n");
    if (c = _getche())
    {
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

Search for a specific record by criteria chosen by the user.

```
void searchrecord(FILE *ptr)
{
    int request;
    int recnum;
    char name[20];
    ogr_t ogr;
    int mark;
    printf("Enter by what criteria do you want to search .\n\n"
        "1- By record num.\n"
        "2- By Name.\n"
        "3- By Grade.\n");
    scanf("%d", &request);
    system("cls");
    switch (request)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter the record number .");
        scanf("%d", &recnum);
        fseek(ptr, (recnum - 1)*sizeof(ogr_t), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&ogr, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
        printf("%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s\n", "RecordNumber", "Name", "Surename", "StudentNum", "MidtermNote", "FinalNote");
        printf("%-13d%-13s%-13s%-13d%-13d%-13d\n", ogr.kyt_no, ogr.ad, ogr.soyad, ogr.ogrno, ogr.vize, ogr.final);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Enter the name of the student .\n ");
        scanf("%s",name);
        rewind(ptr);
        fread(&ogr, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
        while (!feof(ptr))
        {
            if (strcmp(name, ogr.ad) == 0)
            {
                printf("%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s\n", "RecordNumber", "Name", "Surename", "StudentNum", "MidtermNote", "FinalNote");
                printf("%-13d%-13s%-13s%-13d%-13d%-13d\n", ogr.kyt_no, ogr.ad, ogr.soyad, ogr.ogrno, ogr.vize, ogr.final);
            }
            fread(&ogr, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Enter the Mark the you want to search for.\n ");
        scanf("%d",&mark);
        printf("The student that had higher than the mark that you've enterd are \n\n");
        rewind(ptr);
        fread(&ogr, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
        while (!feof(ptr))
        {
            if (ogr.kyt_no!=0)
            {
                ogr.ort = ((ogr.final) + (ogr.vize)) / 2;
                if ((ogr.ort)>=mark)//print the records that have a higher averager than the mark.
                {
                    printf("%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s%-13s\n", "RecordNumber", "Name", "Surename", "StudentNum", "MidtermNote", "FinalNote");
                    printf("%-13d%-13s%-13s%-13d%-13d%-13d\n", ogr.kyt_no, ogr.ad, ogr.soyad, ogr.ogrno, ogr.vize, ogr.final);
                }
            }
            fread(&ogr, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, ptr);
        }
        break;
    default:printf("Undefined choice.\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

End of the program .

Comment: (1) Please format your code with proper indentations. This is really hard to read. (2) That is a lot of code. Please edit your post and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is WAY too much code for getting a useful answer, and you're not even giving a runnable program in one place. But I noticed that `creatfile` will empty the contents of the file, if it exists. Is that intentional?

Comment: In `creatfile` you forgot to close your file after you finished writing to it.

Comment: @alexis in the main() function the user i asked between creating the file or continue if it's already created so the file will be created by the user's demand only , but if you chose to open the file as "wb" all the info will be lost the problem is i'm running the program , i'm choosing to create the file at the first run and enter some records , at the second run i choose not to create a new file because it's already created , instead i want to continue to read the records , but it's lost even if i don't create the file again !

Comment: you're genius @PaulR the problem solved thanks a loooooot
i read the code like 100 times i couldn't notice that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases first things i do is...

> Make sure for every fopen() call there is one fclose() call.

So here in createfile() you fopen in write mode file and do not close that file.. open that file again with rb+ mode so that is causing problem.

You should close file in createfile() after writing that so your code will be like

```
void creatfile()
{
FILE *fp;
ogr_t bos_ogr = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, "", "" };
if ((fp = fopen("kayit.dat", "wb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("File was not opened");
}
else
{   //to create a file and initialize it with an empty 100 student record .
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&bos_ogr, sizeof(ogr_t), 1, fp);
    }//end for

    //Lets close the file         
    fclose(fp);
}
system("cls");
}
```